# Printing multiple layers using household inkjet printer

Tags: linux, printing, hardware, device-driver

**Question.**
Is there application or package thal allows to print several layers with usual household printers? Is it usually tehnically possible at all? I prefer Linux OS.

**Clarification of question.**
For sake if argument lets suppose that we are talking about any cheap HP inkjet printer that has printing matrix inside cartridge.
I am interested in printing objects that are smaller than sheet of paper.

**Relevance.**
Easeast way to obtain multylayer coatings with household inkjet printer is to repeat printing several times. If I do that than there will be some possitioning error.

**My research.**
I found that HP printers use PCL language to communicate with OS, maybe answer should has to do something with it. I gues if there is possibility to tell the printer to move paper backwords and than to repear the task than it should do the job.

Comment: Layers of what? Inkjet printer print very small drops of ink, which a liquid drop with effectively no 3D structure. And trying to use different liquid will not work because of the physics a printing head bases on (both techniques like Bubblejet or Piezo).

Comment: Layers of ink. I just want more thick layers of ink, thicker than usual.

Comment: As I wrote I don't think this is possible because of the physics used by the printers.